# add top quatation mark in a string, in mql4

Tags: c++, c, string, list, mql4

in mql4,

```
string list[]= {"EUR","CHF","GBP","JPY","AUD","CAD","NZD","CHF"};
for(int i=0; i<ArraySize(list); i++) string primer=list[i];
 {
 
  for(i=0; i<ArraySize(list); i++)
 {
 string second =list[i];   
 string currency = StringConcatenate(primer, second);
 }
 }
```

currency output is CHFCHF. how can i fix it to change "CHFCHF" instead of CHFCHF ?
i don't add top quotation mark in mql4. Thank you.

Comment: Is this your real code?  `primer` is no longer in scope when you try to use it.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you expect from the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

if it is
`string currency = StringConcatenate(primer, second);`
output is CHFCHF.
if

```
string currency = StringConcatenate("\"",primer, second,"\"");
```

output is "CHFCHF" and that is main point to send order later.
thank you everybody